# Subtracting variables from a Prolog knowledge base

Tags: prolog

I am trying to write a predicate `duration/2` which – given a leader as first parameter - succeeds
with the number of years of the leader in office. For simplification, I want it to count the initial/final
year of their term in full, which e.g. means that count 1834 as a full year for four
people. If a leader had more than one stint in office, `duration/2` should compute the sum of the
lengths of all their stints.

This is the knowledge base that I have made so far:

```
leader('Chamberlain',1937,1940).
leader('Churchill',1940,1945).
leader('Attlee',1945,1951).
leader('Churchill',1951,1955).
leader('Eden',1955,1957).
leader('Macmillan',1957,1963).
leader('DouglasHome',1963,1964).
```

Comment: I would suggest that you start with a simplified problem by assuming that each leader had a single term. That will result in a definition of a predicate that can then be used to solve the full problem.

Comment: I don't see a specific question here. What have you tried? What specific problem have you encountered?

Comment: The exactly same question has [two answers already](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35909898/aggregate-solution-for-multiple-facts).